# How to redirect all HTTP request to HTTPS on glassfish

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, glassfish

I have tried putting the following on my web.conf

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>SecureResource</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <user-data-constraint>
        <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
    </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

But when I publish I get a "Too many redirects" on chrome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you are running Glassfish behind a load balancer on AWS, and SSL termination is happening at the load balancer.

You need to configure Glassfish to check the `x-forwarded-proto` header to determine if the client is connecting via HTTP or HTTPS. You can do this via the scheme-mapping parameter in your `domain.xml` file:

```
<http default-virtual-server="server"
      max-connections="100"
      scheme-mapping="X-Forwarded-Proto">
```

Alternatively, you can run this command on the server to set the `scheme-mapping` value:

```
asadmin set server.network-config.protocols.protocol.http-listener-1.http.scheme-mapping=X-Forwarded-Proto
```

Comment: That is exactly what I am trying to do. My project doesn't have a domain.xml, how can I generate one? I am using netbeans. Or can I just create a "domain.xml" under web-inf and paste it there?

Comment: I haven't used Glassfish in years, but I think the `domain.xml` file is a server configuration file, not a project file. You would need to SSH into your EC2 server(s) and update the file there. Also see my update to an alternate way to set this.

Comment: Thanks, will try that, one more question, after I manage to change the domain.xml I still need that piece of code on web.conf I posted originally?

Comment: Yes, the update just tells Glassfish how to determine if the client is connected via HTTPS. You still have to have your previous configuration change to tell Glassfish that HTTPS is a requirement.

Comment: Thank you, that looks like to be it, too bad apparently I don't have an associated key par to my instance, and wont be able to log in via ssh. Guess I will wait till I have the time to drop that instance and create a new one. Thanks, that helped a lot

Comment: I'm curious how you deployed your project to Glassfish on the server if you don't have an SSH key. Are you using Elastic Beanstalk? If so you should configure a container command in your Beanstalk config to run the `asadmin` command.

Comment: yes, I have been using elastik beanstalk, will try and find more info on the container command, thank you again, if I find how to do that it will save me a good amount of time :)

Comment: Yeah you need to do it via the container command instead of SSH anyway, as Elastic Beanstalk will automatically create and delete servers for you based on application load, and it needs to be configured to automatically set that value whenever it creates a new server.

Comment: It's still handy to be able to SSH into Elastic Beanstalk servers, to watch logs and debug issues. You shouldn't make changes to an EB server via SSH though.

Comment: Yea, I will try get access anyways, but can you get me some directions on how to set those commands via container? Can't find much information about it on the web

Comment: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html#linux-container-commands

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135614/discussion-between-marcel-caferati-and-mark-b).